# I got a problem with send a random message from DRF to all users(Aiogram)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, aiogram

The code doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't work the way I would like it to. It doesn't send the message to the users. I put a print on the time function, but apparently it didn't work. I've been messing around with this for a very long time and don't understand where I went wrong

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import exceptions

from servises.advertisement_services import advertisements_service
from servises.subscription_services import subscription_service

async def send_message(user_id, message):
try:
await Bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=message, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
except exceptions.BotBlocked:
print(f"Target \[ID:{user_id}\]: blocked by user")
except exceptions.ChatNotFound:
print(f"Target \[ID:{user_id}\]: invalid user ID")
except exceptions.RetryAfter as e:
print(f"Target \[ID:{user_id}\]: Flood limit is exceeded. Sleep {e.timeout} seconds.")
await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)
return await send_message(user_id, message)
except exceptions.TelegramAPIError:
print(f"Target \[ID:{user_id}\]: failed")

async def send_message_to_all_users(message):
users = subscription_service.get_users()
for user in users:
user_id = user\['account_id'\]
await send_message(user_id, message)

async def send_random_message_to_all_users():
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
print(f"Current time: {current_time}")
if current_time == '17:20':
response = advertisements_service.all_advertisement()
messages = response.json()
message = random.choice(messages)
await send_message_to_all_users(message)

async def scheduler():
while True:
await send_random_message_to_all_users()
await asyncio.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(scheduler())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please reformat your code to valid Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code:

```
async def send_message(user_id, message):
    try:
        await Bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=message, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    except exceptions.BotBlocked:
        print(f"Target [ID:{user_id}]: blocked by user")
    except exceptions.ChatNotFound:
        print(f"Target [ID:{user_id}]: invalid user ID")
    except exceptions.RetryAfter as e:
        print(f"Target [ID:{user_id}]: Flood limit is exceeded. Sleep {e.timeout} seconds.")
        await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)
        return await send_message(user_id, message)
    except exceptions.TelegramAPIError:
        print(f"Target [ID:{user_id}]: failed")


async def send_message_to_all_users(message):
    users = subscription_service.get_users()['results']
    for user_info in users:
        account_id = user_info['account_id']
        await send_message(account_id, message)

async def send_random_message_to_all_users():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    print(f"Current time: {current_time}")
    if current_time == '14:23':
        advertisement = advertisements_service.get_random_advertisement()
        message = (f"_______ADVERTISEMENT_______\n"
                   f"{advertisement['name']}\n"
                   f"{advertisement['title']}\n"
                   f"{advertisement['price']}\n"
                   f"{advertisement['url']}\n"
                   f"Seller: @{advertisement['username']} \n"
                   f"_______________________________")
        await send_message_to_all_users(message)

async def scheduler():
    while True:
        try:
            await send_random_message_to_all_users()
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error occurred in the scheduler:", e)
            traceback.print_exc()




print("scheduler running at", datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.create_task(scheduler())
    loop.run_until_complete(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
```